# vscode text coloring inside HTML script tag

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I would like JS `<script type="xx">` content to be colored nicely inside my HTML document.

Right now, when adding the `type` to a script tag, the element text becomes uniform white, as seen below.

[image]

Of course, the JS code is colored nicely within the HTML if removing the `type` attribute.

Is there some setting I can modify to make this work?

Comment: vscode only supports `JS` and `CSS` highlighting within `html` files within script/style tags. There might be a plugin for it, or you could create one...

Comment: Switching the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) to `Handlebars` seems to work nicely

Answer (score 3):

No setting to modify.  This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25920).  From the thread it looks like syntax highlighting was working at one point for script tags with the type attribute but was lost.

Hopefully it's fixed soon. I'm seeing the same thing on VSCode 1.13.1.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, this issue seems to be closed. Should probably be re-opened?

Comment: Looks like it.  From the discussion I don't think it's been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way, if you have an html file and a custom type and syntax highlighted as javascript follow these instructions:

1. locate the VSCode folder, mine is:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes
```

2. open `html.tmLanguage.json`
3. search for `jscript` in the file
4. add `| ractive|` after `| jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  |`

should look like this:

```
| jscript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  | ractive | livescript\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  |
```

5. save the file
6. close vsvode and relaunch!!!

source https://forum.camunda.io/t/syntax-highlighting-for-cam-script-in-vsc/15218/2

the result (image)
[the resulting hightlighting; not perfect but will do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm9k7.png)